# Quasar framework: Opening a q-dialog from a q-table row, opens the dialog for every row in table

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

first of all, sorry for bad english, I'm improving that too.
Hello, i'm quite new in using vuejs with quasar framework. I want to open the details from a row in a modal (q-dialog), I have a button to edit and delete, but the open button used to see the details from one register is attached to the name in the row as a link.
when I click on it, it opens the dialog, yay. but it opens it for every register in the table. I made logs for the connection to database on each click and it repeats for every register in table.

my code.

```
    <q-table
      table-header-class="bg-grey-3 text-grey-9 "
      :rows="rows"
      :columns="columns"
      :row-key="columns[0].name"
      :separator="separator"
      :filter="search"
    >
      <template v-slot:body-cell-usuario="props">
        <q-td :props="props">
          <div>
            <q-btn @click="modalDetalle = true"> {{ props.row.usuario }}</q-btn>
          </div>
          <q-dialog v-model="modalDetalle">
            <component :is="verDetalle" :id="props.key" @reload="getStatus" />
          </q-dialog>
        </q-td>
      </template>
```

Comment: Hello Noe, welcome to SO. What is your specific problem? Seen your code, every row has a cell that shows the username and when you click it you open a QDialog passing an ID as a prop. Again, What's the problem here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can't put the q-dialog in body-cell slot it will create new dialog for each row

Comment: Move the dialog after the q-table and write one method to open the dialog and one variable to store the clicked row data and it will work

Comment: That's exactly the problem, if I move the q-dialog outside the <template> tag from the body-cell, the modal never shows up. but if i keep it inside the q-table or the q-td it creates a dialog for every row and show them up.

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy please `refer` this codepen.

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/dydZyEY

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot, I fixed it making a function based on your codepen. For some reason I cannot upvote your comment. But for everyone facing the same Issue, you're the lifesaver.

Comment: Ok it requires few reputation but you can accept the answer